# Nodejs download binary octet-stream

Tags: node.js, http, pdf, http-headers, mime

I am trying to download (meaning create an instance of the file on the server) a .pdf file from a server that returns it to me in binary format, with:
`Content-Type = application / octet-stream`.

After a bit of online research I came to write:

```js
http.get(url.parse(pdfURL), res => {
    let data = [];
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        data.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        let buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
        console.log(buffer.toString('base64'));
        fs.open(path, 'w', (e, fd) => {
            if (e) throw e;
            fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, e => {
                if (e) throw e;
                fs.close(fd, () => console.log('Wrote successfully'));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works properly, but when I try to open the generated pdf, it tells me that the file is corrupt and not readable.
Any idea what might have been wrong?

Thanks

---

Edit:
I noticed that with postman everything works as it should, so I think the way I treat the binary is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it,
I wasn't de-gzipping the response, now works properly

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, tried so many different ways until I found `got`, an npm library that handles http requests, here's what worked for me:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const got = require('got');

const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

async function downloadImage(url, name) {
  await pipeline(
    got.stream(url),
    fs.createWriteStream(name)
  );
}
```

More info here: https://bleext.com/post/downloading-images-with-nodejs